# Change size of the time textbox

Tags: datetime

I want to change the size of the time textbox but I can't find a way to do it.

```
    $form['feld']['start'] = array(
        '#type' => 'date_popup',
        '#title' => 'Start',
        '#size' => 10,
        '#date_formant' => 'd.m.Y',
        '#date_year_range' => '0:+1', 
        '#default_value' => date('Y-m-d H:i'),
        '#date_timezone' => 'Europe/Rome',
        '#date_increment' => 15,    
        '#required' => TRUE,
);
```

`'#size' => 10` only effects the date textbox.

This is an example.

> [image: screenshot]

How do I alter also the size of the textbox used for the time?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [source code](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/date/tree/date_popup/date_popup.module) it appears that both date and time have a #size key. I don't have time to test this, but you might be able to access it from the 'time' element of the field.

```
$form['feld']['start']['time']['#size'] = 10;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately this doesn't work. I found someone with the same problem but also no solution.
https://www.drupal.org/node/1258952